# Want to use a variable inside if outside of it in awk command

Tags: linux, awk, conditional-statements

```
awk < MigStat.stat -F: '{ if ($a == "load")b=8; } $1 == "D0001" && FNR== '$c' {print $b}'
```

now i want the print the value present in column $b but in this case it prints the whole line.
What i want do is use the value of b from the if statement to print the value in that column

Comment: You need to read and understand http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 then try again.

Answer (score 2):

To pass in values use the `-v` option:

```
awk -F: -v a=2 -v c=10 '$a=="load"{b=8}$1=="D0001"&&FNR==c{print $b}' MigStat
```

Notes:

- To pass in variables use the `-v` option of `awk`.
- `awk` reads file you don't need to use redirection.
- The structure of `awk` is `condition{block}`.
- `awk` initialises variable to `0` so if `b` hasn't been set in the block `$a=="load"{b=8}` then `{print $b}` will be `{print $0}` where `$0` is the whole line.

Comment: i tried out your way but it still gives the whole line as output

Comment: That means that the condition `$a=="load"` is never true in the file then.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need redundantly assigning `b=8` . If the script is like what you posted there, you don't need the `$b` at all.

if `$a, $c` are shell variables:

```
awk -F: -v a="$a" -v c="$c" 'a=="load"&&$1=="D0001"&&NR==c{print $8;exit}' MigStat.stat
```

and better after `print $8` call `exit;` to stop awk processing further lines.